# C Program Web API call from AngularJS $http

Tags: c++, c, communication, angularjs-http

How I can give call to **C Program Web API** from AngularJS $http request?

**AngularJS $htt**p part has been already **done**. But I m new to C Program. 
I want to know: How my $http URI and C program Web API will communicate?

How my **$http URI** will call to particular **Web API in C program**?

> (Please, note: I want **C program** example code)

Comment: Maybe it would help, to show the snippets you think are relevant to show us, so we can offer ideas on how it might work. If you just need a simple C program, there must be plenty "hello world" programs out there, if it's specific for your "Web API", you might find samples in the documentation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. It is like I m sending request for some data from angularJS's $http, and I have some web api in c language. And i have to communicate them.

Comment: I am confused: If I call say `http://api.example.com/get/that?id=1` I do not even know, what implements the answer. It may be a binary compiled from C code that handles the API quest and the http traffic, or a php page run by an interpreter behind a http server. What is specific ot C here? Maybe others simply know ...